# How to exclude a collection of records with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following:

```
= select :client, :id, User.all.map {|u| [u.username, u.id]}, include_blank: "Add a client by username"
```

I'd like to exclude all records from User.all that match `current_user.manager_users`. The point is so that the select box doesn't show users that are already added to the manager_users array which is a `has_many` collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that:

```
= select :client, :id, User.where("users.id NOT IN (?)", current_user.manager_users.pluck(:client_id)).map {|u| [u.username, u.id]}, include_blank: "Add a client by username"
```

The new stuff is here:

```
User.where("users.id NOT IN (?)", current_user.manager_users.pluck(:client_id))
    .map{ |u| [u.username, u.id] }
```

The `current_user.manager_users.pluck(:client_id)` part will retrieve (only on the DB-level) all the client_IDs of the manager_users linked to the current_user.

Hope this helps!

Comment: PGError: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT id FROM "users" INNER JOIN "managers" ON "users"."id"...
               ^
: SELECT id FROM "users" INNER JOIN "managers" ON "users"."id" = "managers"."user_id" WHERE "managers"."client_id" = 1

Comment: has_many :managers, :foreign_key => :client_id
  has_many :manager_users, :through => :managers, :source => :user
  has_many :clients, :class_name => "Manager"
  has_many :client_users, :through => :clients, :source => :client

Comment: class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client, :class_name => "User"
end

Comment: If you're getting `unambiguous line` then change from `select(:id)` to `select("users.id")` or `select("managers.id")` depending on which id you need.

Comment: Thanks I got it. I had to use     @unique_clients = User.where("id NOT IN (?)", current_user.client_users.pluck(:client_id))
 instead of manager_users

Comment: helped my case too. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
# in your controller
ids = current_user.manager_users.pluck(:id)
@users = User.where("id not in (?)", ids).map { |u| [u.username, u.id] }
```

And then use `@users` in the form.

Comment: Ahah, you are 11 seconds in late!

Answer (score 1):

The answers involving NOT IN are inherently inefficient because you are making 2 queries where you only need 1, and passing all the IDs back and forth.

I'm guessing that manager_users is a self join on User.  Something like:

```
has_many :manager_users, class_name: User, foreign_key: :manager_id
```

You need to come at the query from the other angle and just apply the opposite logic as what is used to generate the current_user.manager_users association.  Do something like:

```
User.where( "manager_id <> ?", current_user.id )
```

Replace manager_id with whatever the correct join column is in your DB.  There is **no reason this should require 2 queries**.

Comment: manager_users is a separate class based on Manager class. has_many :managers, :foreign_key => :client_id has_many :manager_users, :through => :managers, :source => :user has_many :clients, :class_name => "Manager" has_many :client_users, :through => :clients, :source => :clien

Comment: @DanielFischer would you mind posting the basic model relationships in your question? It's hard to make out in the comments.